# Viewpager Bottom Padding Skipping with custom ScrollingViewBehavior

Tags: android

I have a tabbed activity and a viewpager whit custom ScrollingViewBehavior for scroll of appbar.
bottom padding of view pager skip when scrolling appbar.
behavior (according to a solution from another post...) is below:

```
public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {

        if (appBarLayout == null) {
            appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) dependency;
            maxTop = 72;
        }

        final boolean result = super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
        int currenttop = dependency.getTop();

        if (currenttop > maxTop)   maxTop = currenttop;
        final int bottomPadding = calculateBottomPadding(appBarLayout);
        final boolean paddingChanged = bottomPadding != child.getPaddingBottom();
        if (paddingChanged) {
            child.setPadding(
                    child.getPaddingLeft(),
                    child.getPaddingTop(),
                    child.getPaddingRight(),
                    bottomPadding);
            child.requestLayout();
        }
        return paddingChanged || result;
    }


    // Calculate the padding needed to keep the bottom of the view pager's content at the same location on the screen.
    private int calculateBottomPadding(AppBarLayout dependency) {
        final int totalScrollRange = dependency.getTotalScrollRange();//getTotalScrollRange();
        final int deptop = dependency.getTop();
        return  deptop + totalScrollRange - maxTop;
    }
}
```

result is (GIF):
[scroll behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvpYj.gif)

why bottom skip?!!

and for a lateral question : in onDependentViewChanged i found a constant value ( maxTop=72) for correct padding!! why?! i cant understand!

tanks for "SOF" and users.

Comment: program checked in other device and constant value did Incorrect !!